# Separating a bootstrap button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to duplicate my "submit" button. When i do that it seems like bootstrap thinks the duplication is apart of the navbar so when i do style="margin-top: 30px;" the navbar basically grows until it reaches the button. See for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/aqs2z6oo/ I would like to know how to just take that button and make it its own so i can move it within the page. I have tried a few things like put the button form in container and row divs but they dont seem to work.

```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" style="position: relative; top: -7.5px;" /></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated linkk</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" size=60px>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.cnn.com')">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Submit

Comment: You should include the Bootstrap CSS as an external resource in your fiddle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aqs2z6oo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to add the closing `nav` HTML tag (it looks like this: `</nav>`). Your code (based on the JsFiddle) would be as follows:

```
<!-- Your Navbar starts here -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" style="position: relative; top: -7.5px;" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated linkk</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" size=60px>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.cnn.com')">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!-- /.your navbar ends here -->

<!-- Here's your submit button, seperated from the navbar -->
<form style="margin-top: 400px;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Open Window" onclick="window.open('http://www.cnn.com')">Submit</button>
</form>
```

An easy way to avoid problems like this in the future is to use a text editor like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), [Atom](https://atom.io/), or [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), each of which will show you whether or not your opening tags are associated with a closing tag. Don't worry though, I know I still make mistakes like this all the time!

Here's the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqs2z6oo/1/).